# fade in and fade out text on click centered

Tags: jquery, center, responsive-design, fade

I want to make something really simple. 
When I click a div I want to display some text centered on any resolution.

Here is my approach:

```
<button>Click</button>
<div id="fade"><a class="close" href="#">&#215;</a>
     <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>

 </div>
```

and this css:

```
#fade {background:red; width:100%; height:150px;}
.close {
color:white;
font:bold 40px Arial,Sans-Serif;
text-decoration:none;    
   }
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KaeT7/7/)
​

Now what I want to do is to center that #fade div  on every screen resolution.

How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *`div` that is always centered vertically and horizontally*

First, you need to set an actual width for the `div`. 100% won't do.
Next, set its `position` to `absolute`;

```
#fade {background:red; width:450px; height:150px; position:absolute;}
```

Then here's the updated jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function() {
    _TOP = (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop();
    _TOP = (_TOP <= 0) ? 0 : _TOP;
    _LEFT= (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft();
    _LEFT = (_LEFT <= 0) ? 0 : _LEFT;
    this.css({
        top:_TOP + "px",
        left:_LEFT + "px"
    });
    return this;
}


$("#fade").center();
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $("#fade").center();
});

$("#fade").hide();
$("button").click(function() {
    
    $("#fade").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").find(".close").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents("#fade").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
    
    $("#fade").center();
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxnPk/)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I center that div based on the screen width and height?

Answer (score 1):

Set text-align property of p tag containing text.

```
<p style="text-align:center">Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/KaeT7/8/)**

Comment: but what if I use height:100%;? how can I centered it vertically ?

Answer (score 1):

For Vertical align set this:

```
#fade {
    background:red; 
    width:100%; 
    height:150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KaeT7/10/)**

Comment: but what if I use height:100% ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, it adds padding for centering the content of div and places the `#fade` div to the middle of screen when onclick via jQuery:

CSS:

```css
#fade { background:red; width:90%; padding:50px 0; text-align:center; position:absolute; }
#fade p { display:inline-block; position:relative; top:-10px;  }
```

Javascript:

```js
$("#fade").hide();
$("button").click(function() {
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var fh = $('#fade').outerHeight();
    var fw = $('#fade').outerWidth();
    $('#fade').css('top', Math.floor((wh-fh)/2)+'px');
    $('#fade').css('left', Math.floor((ww-fw)/2)+'px');
    $("#fade").fadeToggle("slow", "linear").find(".close").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents("#fade").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, then use css instead, for example `#fade { margin:50px auto; }` but then it won't be centered vertically.

[And the fiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/KaeT7/17/)